# Move folder to parent directory

Tags: file, batch-file, move

I've been searching for the right batch file command but still cannot find any solutions. Please help me with this

My usb drive (j:) have a folder name called "Inventory", inside the folder "inventory" have plenty of folders & files with spaces example for the folder "Soda Coke" "soda pepsi" etc and files like "soda coke.doc", "soda pepsi.doc"

my question is how can i move all files from "inventory" folder to my usb root directory?

to MOVE `j:\Inventory\"all files & folders"` with or without spaces to `j:\` only and after moving all files to `j:\`, the "Inventory" folder will be deleted

Hope you could give me the perfect batch file command.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The usb folder & files structure as follows: j:\Inventory, j:\inventory\Soda Coke, j:\inventory\Soda Pepsi, j:\Inventory\soda coke.doc, j:\soda pepsi.doc, j:\Inventory\Soda Coke\230ml.doc etc....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rem Moves your files
for /r "j:\Inventory\" %%x in (*.*) do move "%%x" "j:\"


Rem OR move files and folders with this
ROBOCOPY "j:\Inventory\" "j:\" /E /move

rem Delete folders
FOR /D %i IN (j:\Inventory\*) DO RD /S /Q "%i"
DEL /Q C:\mydir\*.*
```

I think this are the commands you're looking for. :)

Comment: Thank you for you reply sir but for /r "j:\Inventory\" %%x in (*.*) do move "%%x" "j:\" only moves the files.. the folders still inside Inventory folder & were not moved on j:\

Comment: Great! Perfect! ROBOCOPY "j:\Inventory\" "j:\" /E /move did the work. Also it auto deletes my inventory folder! thank you so so much!